# For $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^+,\ a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6-1=\sqrt{ 2(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}.$ Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^6a_i\leq\frac{3}{2}.$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

For $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^+,\ a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6-1=\sqrt{ 2(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}.$

Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^6a_i\leq\frac{3}{2}.$$

I applied A.M.$\geq$G.M. but that didn't work as terms are not same. How do I proceed this question?

Comment: @AdamRubinson it is been more clarified now.

Comment: The solution of this problem is **not very long**. I recommend not to close the question

Comment: What does $\sum a_1$ mean? Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^6a_i$? Also, the question is severely lacking in context, Check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619), study it, and fix the post. If you pressed for time, there is [the abridged version](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619).

Comment: @Siddharth. I know, but that's not a reason for the question to remain open. The same argument would apply to most homework questions dumped here.

Comment: And for heaven's sake fix the title, and use full sentences.

Comment: "Where," what? And again, what does $\sum a_1$ mean?

Comment: And why does this square root exist?

Comment: Yes obviously $\sum{a_1}=\sum_{i=1}^{6}{a_i}$. What could be the other meaning for that?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree with you. But user had written his trial for the question too.

Comment: Now that you've amended the question, I've retracted both my downvote and vote to close.

Comment: @Anonymous When you listed out $ \sum a_1 a_2$, it's unclear if you meant "sum of consecutive terms" or "sum of any cross terms". $\quad$ Furthermore, note that your first version of the problem is distinct from this. since the term $a_1a_2$ doesn't even appear. Clarity in the problem statement is important, since we can't read your mind.

Comment: @CalvinLin yes I completely agree the previous version was wrong. But $\sum a_1a_2$ Only mean that sum of numbers taken two at a time.You should assume it to be trivial what could be its meaning. Don't assume anything else if not written. Since you can't read my mind.

Comment: @Anonymous I disagree. $\sum_{i=1}^k a_1 a_2 = k a_1 a_2$ by definition, so that's the "trivial" interpretation I would be assuming. (And I guess that's why Jyrki asked)  $\sum a_i a_j$ means sum of cross terms. $\sum a_i a_{i+1}$ means product of consecutive terms.

Comment: @CalvinLin yes I agree with you. But if I was intentioned to write $ka_1a_2$, I would have wrote that, Form the schools to now if I had to write the summation of product of two numbers taken at a time. I and even my teacher used $\sum a_1a_2$. It's not my fault and neither yours.

Comment: 1) Sometimes people do that because they don't know better, or to hide some facts (EG The substitution of $ a = a_1 + a_2$ in this question).  2) Yea, I can't fault you for learning incorrectly. But now that you know better, I can only hope that you use the right notation to discuss outside of our classroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us replace,

$a_1+a_2=a, a_3+a_4=b, a_5+a_6=c$

The equation will be reduced to,

$$a+b+c=1+4\sqrt{\frac{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}{8}}$$

If you look $a, b, c$ taking cases.(Symmetrically make other cases)

**1.) $0<a,b,c<1$ :**

Which is completely true.

**2.) $0<a,b<1<c$ :**

It can't be true. Since square root can't contain negative term here.

**3.) $0<a<1<b,c$ :**

If you look at the the expression,

$$a+b+c-1=\sqrt{2(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}$$
If the statement down is true then this case also will be rejected.
$$b+c-1(=LHS)>\sqrt{2(1-b)(1-c)}(RHS)-(1)$$
As the inequality given down will also be true.
$$LHS+a(\in(0,1))>\sqrt{2(1-b)(1-c)(1-a)}$$

Which was our expression in equality originally.

> $(1-a)$ will make RHS smaller and adding a will make LHS larger. The in equality will be still true.

So, for proving $-(1)$,  let $b-1=u, c-1=v$

We'll now proving,

$$\sqrt{2uv}<u+v+1$$

Which you can prove by,

$$\sqrt{2uv}<2\sqrt{uv}<u+v<u+v+1$$

Hence this case is also rejected.

**4.) $1<a,b,c:$**

Which is again false as square root can't contain negative term here.

Only case 1 is true i.e. $0<a,b,c<1$

So, let $a=\cos \alpha, b= \cos \beta,  c= \cos \gamma$

Also, $\frac{1-a}{2}=\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$

The above equations gets reduced to,

$$\cos \alpha+\cos \beta+cos \gamma=$$$$1+4\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sin{\frac{\beta}{2}}\sin{\frac{\gamma}{2}}$$

Which is equivalent to $ \alpha + \beta  + \gamma = \pi$

You can see proof [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-displaystyle-a-b-c-pi-prove-thatdisplaystyle-cos-a/).

Where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma< \frac{\pi}{2}$ (as $a$ was positive real)

Now we know if $ \alpha+ \beta + \gamma=\pi$,
$$\cos \alpha+\cos \beta+cos \gamma\leq \frac{3}{2}$$
You can see proof [here](https://byjus.com/question-answer/if-a-b-c-pi-the-maximum-value-of-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-1/).
Or,

$$a+b+c\leq \frac{3}{2}⇒\sum_{i=1}^6{a_i}\leq \frac{3}{2} $$

> I am not writing the proves of above two claims because it will make answer too long. So, posted proves in link.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the statement to be proved can be simplified to the following equivalent statement:

> Suppose $\ a,b,c > 0\ $ and $\ a + b + c - 1 \overset{(*)}{=}
>  \sqrt{2(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}.\ $ Then, $\ a + b + c \leq \frac{3}{2}.$

$$$$
*Proof*: First we note that, since $\ a,b,c > 0,\ $ it follows that $\ a + b + c > 0.$

Now, in order for the right-hand side (RHS) of $\ (*)\ $ to exist, either:

(i) Two of $\ a,b,c\ $ are $\ > 1\ $ and the other one is $\ \leq 1,\ $ or

(ii) $\ a,b,c\ $ are all $\ \leq 1.$

We deal with the two cases separately.

(i) Suppose WLOG that $\ a,b > 1;\ c\leq 1.\ $ Then, since $\ 0<c\leq 1,\ $

$$ \text{RHS }\ (*)\ < \sqrt{ 2(1-a)(1-b) } = \sqrt{ 2(a-1)(b-1) } \overset{AM-GM}{<} \sqrt{ 2}\ \cdot\ \frac{(a-1) + (b-1) }{ 2} $$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ \cdot\ (a+b-2) < a+b-2 < a + b - 1 < a + b + c - 1 =\ \text{ LHS }\ (*),\ $$contradicting equality $\ (*).$

So far we have shown that (i) cannot happen. Therefore it must be the case that:

(ii) $\ a,b,c\ $ are all $\ \leq 1.\ $ Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $\ a + b + c > \frac{3}{2},\ $ so we have $\ \frac{3}{2} < a + b + c \leq 3.\ $ Note that this implies that LHS $\ (*)\ > \frac{1}{2}.\ $ But it also implies that RHS $\ (*)\ < \frac{1}{2},\ $ which I prove presently.

$$\ 0 \leq 3 - (a + b + c) < \frac{3}{2}, \implies 0 < (1-a) + (1-b) + (1-c) < \frac{3}{2},$$

$$\implies 0 < \frac{ (1-a) + (1-b) + (1-c) }{3} < \frac{1}{2}.$$

$$\text{AM-GM }\ \implies \sqrt[3]{ (1-a)(1-b)(1-c) } \leq \frac{ (1-a) + (1-b) + (1-c) }{3} < \frac{1}{2},$$

$$\implies (1-a)(1-b)(1-c) < \frac{1}{8} \implies \sqrt{2(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) } < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} }\cdot \sqrt{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

We have shown that the assumption $\ a + b + c > \frac{3}{2}\implies\ $ LHS$(*) > \frac{1}{2},\ $ whereas RHS$(*) < \frac{1}{2},\ $ a contradiction. Therefore, it must be the case that $\ a + b + c \leq \frac{3}{2}.$

Comment: I dealt with case 1 in a similar manner. In fact, any solution with $a, b > 1$ will require $ c \leq -1$ (which isn't allowed), like with $ a = b , c = -1$. In that sense, the all-positive condition is crucial to the conclusion $ a + b + c \leq 3/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $1-a_1-a_2=x$, $1-a_3-a_4=y$ and $1-a_5-a_6=z$. Now the condition transforms into
$$2-x-y-z=\sqrt{2xyz}.$$
If $x$, $y$ and $z\ge0$, assume $x+y+z<\dfrac32$, $\textsf{AM-GM}$ yields contradiction:
$$\sqrt{2xyz}+x+y+z\le\sqrt{2\left(\frac{x+y+z}3\right)^3}+x+y+z<2.$$

Otherwise WLOG they're $x$ and $y<0$ while $z>0$. Let $m=-x$ and $n=-y>0$. Then
$$2+m+n-z=\sqrt{2mnz}\le(m+n)\sqrt{\frac z2}.$$So $2-z\le(m+n)\left(\sqrt{\dfrac z2}-1\right)$. We see that $z>2$, otherwise the left side $>0$ and the right side $<0$, contradiction. But $a_5+a_6=1-z<-1$, contradicts with $a_{5,6}\in\Bbb R_+$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6-1=\sqrt{2(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6-1)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}=\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{2}(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}\right)^2$$
By the AM-GM inequality, $$\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{2}(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}\right)^2\le \left(\frac{\frac{7}{2}-a_1-a_2-a_3-a_4-a_5-a_6}{4}\right)^2$$
Let $$s=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(s-1)\le\left(\frac{\frac{7}{2}-s}{4}\right)^2=\left(\frac{7-2s}{8}\right)^2$$
$$32(s-1)\le(7-2s)^2$$
$$32s-32\le4s^2-28s+49$$
$$4s^2-60+81=(2s-3)(2s-27)\ge0$$
If $s\ge\frac{27}{2}$ then $s-1\ge\frac{25}{2}$, but since $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$ and $a_6$ are positive, $\sqrt{2(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}\le\sqrt2$, so there is a contradiction, and we can conclude that $$s=\sum_{i=1}^6{a_i}\le\frac{3}{2}$$ with equality when $$a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=a_5=a_6=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $a_1 + a_2 \leq 1$, etc? If so, why is that valid?

Comment: @CalvinLin Because the term is inside the $\sqrt{1-a_1-a_2}$ which can't be nevative if you are assuming. So, only one of $a_i+a_{i+1}$ can't be greater. And also all 3 can't be greater than 1. If you are assuming any two are greater than 1 and other isn't, the equality wouldn't hold.

Comment: Right, so my question is why can't 2 of them be $> 1$.

Comment: I said using that by using the AM-GM inequality, $\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{2}(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}\right)^2\le \left(\frac{\frac{7}{2}-a_1-a_2-a_3-a_4-a_5-a_6}{4}\right)^2$, but my reasoning for this was that $\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{2}(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}\le \frac{\frac{7}{2}-a_1-a_2-a_3-a_4-a_5-a_6}{4}$. The $RHS$ is negative if $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6\ge\frac{27}{2}$, but since the $LHS$ is a square root, and so is non-negative. So $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6\ge\frac{27}{2}$ is not a valid solution.

Comment: Okay Calvin, assume 2 of them to be just greater than one. Then you'll see the 3rd one will be negative. Which is contradicting

Comment: You can't apply AM-GM IF the terms are negative, so that invalidates that step (and the subsequent conclusion).

Comment: I agree that "if 2 of them are greater than one, then the 3rd one will be negative". However, that still needs to be shown, or at least stated explicitly.

Comment: Let $a_1+a_2,a_3+a_4>1$ and $a_5+a_6<1$. $s-1=\sqrt{2(1-a_1-a_2)(1-a_3-a_4)(1-a_5-a_6)}<\sqrt2\sqrt{(a_1+a_2-1)(a_3+a_4-1)}$$\le\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4-2)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(s-2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(s-1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, which is contradictory when $s\ge\frac{27}{2}$.

Comment: But you do not have $ s \geq 27/2$ (which is a subsequent conclusion of the AM-GM, which we cannot apply). $\quad$ I'm not sure if what you have here can work.

Comment: For clarity, note that the (tweaked-original) AM-GM we'd apply in this case is $\sqrt[4]{ \frac{1}{2} ( a_1 + a_2 - 1) ( a_3 + a_4 - 1) (1 - a_5-a_6) }  \leq  \frac{- \frac{1}{2} + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 - a_5 - a_6 } { 4}$. This doesn't give information about $s$ as yet (but perhaps we can tweak it, esp since we know $a_5+a_6 \leq 1$).