# Find the maximum value of $xy+yz+xz-2xyz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If $x+y+z=1$ and $0\le x,y,z\le1$ then find the maximum value of expression $$xy+yz+xz-2xyz$$

Solution that I have

$$(1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z)=1-2\sum x+4\sum xy-8xyz=4\sum xy-8xyz-1$$
$\implies$
$$\sum xy-2xyz=\frac{1+(1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z)}{4}$$
Now
$$\frac{\sum(1-2x)}{3}\ge\{(1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z)\}^{\frac13}$$
$$\implies (1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z)\le\frac{1}{27}$$
$$\implies xy+yz+xz-2xyz\le\frac{1+\frac{1}{27}}{4}=\frac{7}{27}$$

My own solution

Consider $f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx-2xyz$

Since $f(x,y,z)$ is symmetric, it will achieve it's maximum value when $x=y=z=\frac13$ thereby giving $\frac{7}{27}$ as the answer.

What I want to know, is whether there is any other practical method to solve this question as considering $(1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z)$ seems somewhat impractical and unimpressive to me. Like how will one think of such expression.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first solution uses AM-GM, which works for positive numbers.  However how do you ensure $1-2x, 1-2y, 1-2z$ are non-negative?  Easily one can have cases where this isn't true.  The second solution seems to say any symmetric function achieves its maximum when the variables are equal, which is not proven and in fact is incorrect as well :(

Comment: A quick way to see this symmetry argument fail is to consider the same problem, but to maximise $-f = 2xyz-(xy+yz+zx)$.  By the argument above, this maximum should also be at $x=y=z=\frac13$, which means the maximum and minimum of $f$ coincide, so it must be a constant which is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: If say $z=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow x+y=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4}$. I believe the problem asks to find the maximum of $F(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx-2xyz$ for any point $(x,y,z)$ in the plane $x+y+z=1$. If $\vec n=(1,1,1)$ respresents the vector normal to the plane, I also believe that solving $\nabla F\times \vec n=\vec 0$ solves the problem

Comment: Think of adding more specific tags to your question, such as [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization).

Comment: @Macavity Agree with the issue you pointed out, though that can be easily fixed: Observe that no 2 of the terms  $1-2x, 1-2y, 1-2z$ can be negative. If one of the terms is negative,then the product is $ \leq 0 \leq 1/27$.  $\quad$ It might be possible that OP's solution dealt with this, but I agree that it's an often neglected situation, like in this [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613735/for-a-i-in-mathbbr-a-1a-2a-3a-4a-5a-6-1-sqrt-21-a-1-a-21-a-3-a).

Comment: @CalvinLin Sure - unless it is mentioned why it's valid in this case, it's hard to accept in general.  Of course also the three term AM-GM holds true for all reals as long as the sum of terms is not negative, which happens to be true in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to use symmetry.

Using symmetry, WLOG let  $x > \max(y,z)$.  Consider replacing both $x$ and $y$ with $s = \frac{x+y}2$ in $f(x) = xy(1-2z)+(x+y)z$. The constraint is unchanged, and the value of $xy$ increases (why?). This means $f(x)$ increases, as $1-2z$ is positive in this case (why).

Hence at any maximum **for this problem**, we cannot have any one variable larger than the others, or the maximum can only be when $x=y=z$.  As the function $f$ is continuous and the domain is compact, we must have a maximum, viz. $f_{\max} = \frac7{27}$ when $x=y=z=\frac13$.

Comment: Pls elaborate this point **Hence at any maximum for this problem,  we cannot have any one variable larger than others.** How is this implying$?$

Comment: If one variable is larger than the others, then we may replace both that variable and any other with their average, to get a larger value for $f$, as demonstrated.  Hence it cannot be the maximum, as we have a higher value possible for $f$.

Comment: Thanks ...i understood

Answer (score 5):

I will do this in two different ways, one is something I came up with ad hoc, and the other will be expanding on the solution you were given in attempt to convince you that it's neither impractical nor unimpressive.

The main takeaway that you should remember from this exercise is the following:

> Given $X,Y,Z\geq 0$ and $X+Y+Z$ constant, $XYZ$ is maximized when $X=Y=Z$ by AM-GM inequality.

The proof is one liner $XYZ \leq \left( \frac{X+Y+Z}3 \right)^3 = \text{constant}$, since it's well known that equality in AM-GM inequality is achieved when $X=Y=Z$. Of course, this works for any number of variables, not just $3$.

---

First let's use the condition $x+y+z = 1$ to write $x+y = 1-z$. Your expression can now be rewritten as
$$xy+yz+zx-2xyz = xy(1-2z) + z(x+y) = xy(1-2z)+z(1-z).\tag1$$

Now, note that we can bound
$$xy \leq \left( \frac{x+y}2 \right)^2 = \left( \frac{1-z}2 \right)^2,\tag2$$

which we would like to multiply by $1-2z$ and use in $(1)$, however, we don't know whether $1-2z$ is positive or not, which is a bit annoying.

So, we first consider the case when $1-2z \leq 0$, and therefore $xy(1-2z)\leq 0$ since we are still under constraint that $x,y\geq 0$. Now we have
$$xy(1-2z)+z(1-z)\leq z(1-z) \leq \frac 14,$$

since $z(1-z)$ is just a quadratic in $z$ with roots $z_1 = 0$ and $z_2 = 1$, so maximum is achieved for $z_0 = \frac 12$.

Interestingly, if you let $z = \frac 12$ in the original expression, since $x+y = \frac 12$ as well, you will get the same value regardless of what $x,y$ are.

Now, consider the (main) case when $1-2z > 0$. Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we now get
\begin{align}
xy+yz+zx-2xyz &= xy(1-2z)+z(1-z) \\ &\leq \left( \frac{1-z}2 \right)^2(1-2z)+z(1-z)\\ &= \frac 14 + \frac 14 z^2(1-2z).\tag3
\end{align}

Notice how both $z,1-2z \geq 0$, so we can use AM-GM inequality to get
$$z^2(1-2z)\leq \left( \frac{z+z+(1-2z)}3 \right)^3 = \frac 1{27}\tag4$$ and using it with $(3)$ gives us
$$xy+yz+zx-2xyz \leq \frac 14 + \frac 14 z^2(1-2z) \leq \frac 14 + \frac 14\cdot \frac 1{27} = \frac 7{27}.$$

To get this upper bound we used AM-GM inequality in $(2)$ and in $(4)$ and equality is, therefore, achieved when $x=y$ and $z = 1-2z$, i.e. $x=y=z = \frac 13$.

Finally, note that $\frac 7{27} > \frac 7{28} = \frac 14$ (i.e. the case $1-2z>0$ gives us greater value than the case $1-2z\leq 0$), so that's the maximum that we are looking for.

---

Now, let's say something about the solution you were given. The expression $$(1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z)$$ is not unmotivated if you know what you are looking for.

First note that you want to maximize $xy+yz+zx-2xyz$ which has two important bits: $xy+yz+zx$ and $xyz$. These are so called [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) which should be familiar if you know, for example, [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), which I mention because a similar idea is at play here.

Since the expression you are given is basically a linear combination of elementary symmetric polynomials, the constraint you are given is $x+y+z = 1$ and $x+y+z$ is another elementary symmetric polynomial, following the same idea as in the proof of Vieta's formulas we might want to consider expression

$$(ax+b)(ay+b)(az+b) = a^3xyz + a^2b(xy+yz+zx)+ab^2(x+y+z) + b^3,$$

and we want to choose $a$ and $b$ that will give us what we want. In our expression, we have coefficient $-2$ multiplying $xyz$ and coefficient $1$ multiplying $xy+yz+zx$, so we want $\frac{a^3}{a^2b} = \frac{-2}{1} \implies a = -2b.$ We can set $b=1$, and therefore $a = -2$ to get

\begin{align}
(1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z) &= -8xyz + 4 (xy+yz+zx) - 2(x+y+z) + 1\\ &= 4(xy+yz+zx-2xyz) - 1
\end{align}
where we used the constraint $x+y+z=1$. Any choice of $b$ will work just as well as this choice and from there you get the expression from the solution you were given.

You can still ask why exactly does considering $(ax+b)(ay+b)(az+b)$, or $(1-2x)(1-2y)(1-2z)$ in our case, gives us anything useful. For that I'm going to write once again the thing I started with

> Given $X,Y,Z\geq 0$ and $X+Y+Z$ constant, $XYZ$ is maximized when $X=Y=Z$ by AM-GM inequality.

Hence, if $ax+b,ay+b,az+b\geq 0$, by AM-GM inequality we have
\begin{align}(ax+b)(ay+b)(az+b) &\leq \left( \frac{(ax+b)+(ay+b)+(az+b)}{3} \right)^3\\ &= \left( \frac{a(x+y+z)+3b}{3} \right)^3 = \left( \frac{a+3b}{3} \right)^3
\end{align}
since $x+y+z=1$.

This is almost the whole story behind the solution you were given, and hopefully what I wrote convinced you that it's not ad hoc improvisation (unlike my solution, which is), but there is something important which was omitted and Macavity mentioned in their first comment. We **need to** make sure $1-2x,1-2y,1-2z\geq 0$ to apply AM-GM.

Luckily, I already showed you how to treat this separately in the solution I improvised. If any of $1-2x$, $1-2y$ or $1-2z$ is negative, which is equivalent to $x>\frac 12$, $y>\frac 12$ or $z>\frac 12$, then at most one is because of the constraint $x+y+z = 1$. WLOG, let $z>\frac 12$. Then, as in $(1)$, write
$$xy+yz+zx-2xyz = xy(1-2z) + z(x+y) = xy(1-2z)+z(1-z) \leq z(1-z)\leq\frac 14,$$ and therefore maximum is not achieved in this case, so we can safely assume $1-2x,1-2y,1-2z\geq 0$.

Comment: Once you understand the first solution I wrote, one can write it more neatly. Note that we  had to consider cases when $1-2z$ is positive or not separately, but we can actually avoid it because at least one of $1-2x$, $1-2y$, $1-2z$ is non-negative because of the constraint $x+y+z = 1$. WLOG let it be $1-2z$. Then, no casework is needed and you can immediately skip to the main case.

Comment: +1...it made my concepts clearer

Comment: To judge from the approach I took, I suspect the function under investigation was deliberately constructed so that $ \ (1 - 2z) \ $ does not have the same sign over the entire triangular region.  For $ \ 0 \ \le \ z \ < \ \frac12 \ , \ $ the points on $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ are relative maxima, but for $ \ \frac12 \ < \ z \ \le \ 1 \ , \ $ they are relative _minima_, forcing an inequality analysis to deal with two cases.  (The change takes place at $ \ z \ = \ \frac12 \ , \ $ where the function has the constant value $ \ \frac14 \ $ on the surface, as you observe.)

Comment: @boojum, I see what you mean. You are likely correct about deliberate construction.

Answer (score 1):

By continuity, $f$ has indeed a maximum on this compact triangle $\overline T.$ By [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), if it is attained at some interior point $(x,y,z)\in T$ (the open triangle), then the three partial derivatives of $f$ must coincide at this point, i.e.
$$y+z-2yz=x+z-2xz=y+x-2xy.$$
One quickly finds that the only solution $(x,y,z)\in T$ (i.e. $x+y+z=1$ and $x,y,z>0$) is $x=y=z=\frac13$, and the value of $f$ at this point is $\frac7{27}.$

There remains to check that the values on $\partial T$ are less: e.g. if $0\le y\le1,$
$$f(0,y,1-y)=y-y^2\le\frac14<\frac7{27}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I know nothing about lagrange, compact triangles and theory of partial derivatives.

Comment: "Compact triangles" is nothing mysterious: only the (useless) remark that the subset $\bar T\subset\Bbb R^3$ which you defined is a triangle, and the (useful) one that it is compact (i.e. bounded and closed), which entails that any continuous function $\bar T\to\Bbb R$ attains a maximum and a minimum value.

Comment: As for Lagrange, I included a link presenting this theorem, which uses the (not complicated) notion of [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative). Here, since the open triangle $T$ sits inside the plane $g(x,y,z)=1$ (where $g(x,y,z):=x+y+z$), this theorem says that if $f$ has an extremum at some $p\in T$ then $(\partial f/\partial x,\partial f/\partial y,\partial f/\partial z)(p)$ must be equal to $\lambda(\partial g/\partial x,\partial g/\partial y,\partial g/\partial z)(p)$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R,$ called a "Lagrange multiplier".

Comment: This simple application of Lagrange's theorem justifies WindSoul's comment above.

Comment: Of course, this is correct, but completely ignores the tag `algebra-precalculus`. OP might as well be a high school student and you are trying to teach them multivariable calculus in comments...

Comment: Your comment is undoubtfully right but not your downvote: this answer could be useful to other future readers, and other tags should be added. Whatever the OP's level is, it cannot be harmful to let him know the existence of useful theorems, really appropriate to his problem. Moreover, as already said, it explains WindSoul's comment.

Comment: My downvote is solely because I don't think this deserves upvotes when it doesn't answer  the question which is basically "optimize this polynomial function without calculus". So, I'm just balancing the number on the left side.

Comment: *You* are reformulating the question. It was literally: "whether there is any other *practical method* to solve this question". No mention of your constraints.

Comment: Tags are part of the question which you ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for posting this answer are:

1. The answers posted are difficult to follow. Maybe not by everyone, but at least by myself. They don’t inspire in the sense that do not follow a natural, progressive, intuitive approach. Somewhere there lies a catch and it feels reading this answers that I am not ready. I can live with that, I just can’t do well not knowing where the disconnect is.
2. The answers (most or all?) employ the concept of averages which I find as elusive as were the irrationals on the times of the Greeks. Or matrices in our time. We could all agree that $p\rightarrow q$ while the axiomatic foundation remains elusive, incomplete.
3. If we ended up using averages to solve an inequality then we might as well use calculus and scalar fields, because learning those concepts is still less difficult than understanding averages.
4. Look at the answer proposed by the OP: is magic. You don’t know the trick, don’t bet your life then.
5. Look at the agreed answer: another magic of distraction from mathematical analysis. “This increases (but why?) so that stays positive (is it?)” is the sort of phrasing that makes sense in a church of some sorts.
6. Then look at my answer: breaking the boundaries of what is accepted, using forbidden mathematical tools for the sake of getting an intuitive and straightforward response.
7. Truth is not a commodity. Never was in the past when Greeks learned from Egyptians who learned from Assyrians and all reached India then back to Algebra and Bonacci’s son. Let’s not rely on magic tricks without even trying to show the straight path to answer.

Let $F(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx-2xyz$ be a scalar function defined on the bounded plane $x+y+z=1, 0\le x,y,z\le1$

The vector normal (perpendicular) to the plane is $\vec n=(1,1,1)$.

The function F has a local maximum or minimum in any point where the gradient is perpendicular to $x+y+z=1$.

The previous condition is equivalent to solving $\nabla F\times \vec n=\vec0$, leading to 3 symmetrical sets of solutions of the kind: $z=\frac{1}{2}\lor x=y$.

For $z=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4}$

For $x=y\Rightarrow F(x,y,z)=x^2+2xz-2x^2z=x^2+2x(1-2x)-2x^2(1-2x), z=1-x-y=1-2x$

Therefore we need to find the local extremes for a cubic polynomial function,
$$f(x)=4x^3-5x^2+2x$$
$$f\prime(x)=0\Rightarrow 6x^2-5x+1=0, x=\frac{5\pm 1}{12}$$

Out of the two values retain $x=\frac{1}{3}$ rendering the maximum value $F(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})=\frac{7}{27}$.

Comment: Everybody just ignoring the tag `algebra-precalculus`...

Comment: @WindSoul when did you learn this thing...in a university??

Comment: Aside from the concept of gradient which is only one definition, the rest is just high school material: a bit of vectors, a bit of optimum/derivatives in terms of horizontal tangent to a function plot. I thought you deserve to have the intuitive and straightforward answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition that the symmetry of both the function and the surface on which the function is to be extremized leads to a simple result is a good one.    Another way in which we can establish that symmetry (without the use of calculus) is to consider the behavior of the function $ \ xy + yz + xz -  2xyz \ $ along the planar surface $ \ x + y + z \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ \ 0 \ \le \  x,y,z \ \le \ 1 \ \ $ (that is, in the first octant) one "strip" at a time.

We find immediately that the value of the function at the vertices $ \ (1 \ , \ 0 \ , \ 0) \ , \ (0 \ , \ 1 \ , \ 0) \ , \ (0 \ , \ 0 \ , \ 1) \   \ $ of this triangular section of the plane is zero.  We can next consider how the function "behaves" at one edge of the triangle, say, the edge in the $ \ xy-$plane.  With $ \ z \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ the equation for this edge is $ \ x + y \ = \ 1 \ $ $ \ \rightarrow \ y \ = \ 1 - x \ \ $ and the function becomes $ \ x·(1-x) \ + \ y·0 \ + \ x·0 \ - \ 2xy·0 \ \ . \  $  By "completing the square", we obtain $ \ x·(1 - x) \ = \ -\left(x - \frac12 \right)^2 + \frac14 \ \ . \ $ Because this quadratic function corresponds to a "downward-opening" parabola, this tells us that the maximum of the function on this edge is $ \ \frac14 \ \ , \ $ occurring at $ \ \left(\frac12 \ , \ \frac12 \ , \ 0 \right) \ \ $ (the midpoint of the edge); as we have seen, the minimum value occurs at the vertices.

We can continue this argument by looking at line segments parallel to this edge at other values of $ \ z \ \ . \ $  For $ \ z \ = \ z_0 \ \ , \ 0 \ \le \ z_0 \ \le \ 1 \ \ , \ $ the segment is on the line $ \ x + y \ = \ 1 - z_0 \ $ and has endpoints $ \ (1 - z_0 \ , \ 0 \ , \ z_0) \ \ $ and $ \ \ (0 \ , \ 1 - z_0 \ , \ z_0)  \ \ .  \ $  On this segment, the function is
$$   x·( \ [1 - z_0] - x \ ) \ + \ ( \ [1 - z_0] - x \ )·z_0 \ +  \ x·z_0 \ - \ 2·x·( \ [1 - z_0] - x \ )·z_0 $$
$$ = \ \ (2z_0 \ - \ 1)·x^2 \ + \ (2z_0^2 \ - \ 3z_0 \ + \ 1)·x \ + \ (z_0 \ - \ z_0^2) $$
$$ = \ \ -(1 \ - \ 2z_0 )·x^2 \ + \ (1 \ - \ 2z_0 )·(1 \ - \ z_0 )·x \ + \  z_0·(1 \ - \ z_0) \ \ , $$
which is again (generally) quadratic.  Completing the square here produces
$$   -(1 \ - \ 2z_0 ) \ · \ \left[ \ x^2  \ - \  (1 \ - \ z_0 )·x \ \right]  \ + \  z_0·(1 \ - \ z_0)   $$
$$   -(1 \ - \ 2z_0 ) \ · \ \left[ \ x   \ - \   \frac{1 \ - \ z_0}{2}    \ \right]^2  \ + \  z_0·(1 \ - \ z_0) \ + \ (1 \ - \ 2z_0 )·\frac{(1 \ - \ z_0)^2}{4}   $$
$$   -(1 \ - \ 2z_0 ) \ · \ \left[ \ x   \ - \   \frac{1 \ - \ z_0}{2}    \ \right]^2  \ + \  \frac14·( \ 1 \ + \ z_0^2 \ - \ 2z_0^3 \ )  \ \ . $$

We note a few points of interest.  First is that this confirms our intuition: the extremal value of the function is found at the *midpoint* of each line segment, $ \ \left(\frac{1 \ - \ z_0}{2} \ , \ \frac{1 \ - \ z_0}{2} \ , \ z_0 \right) \  $ ; thus, the point where the extremum lies is in the plane $ \ y \ = \ x \ \ . \ $  Secondly, the nature of the extremum changes along this bisector of the triangular region:  for $  \ 0 \ \le \ z_0 \ < \ \frac12 \ \ , \ $ the parabola corresponding to the quadratic function "opens downward", so the extremum is a *maximum* along the line segment; but for $  \ \frac12 \ < \ z_0 \ \le \ 1 \ \ , \ $ the parabola "opens upward", making the extremum a *minimum*.  Third, the "curvature" of the function-surface changes direction at the "transition value" $ \ z_0 \ = \ \frac12 \ \ , \ $ where the function is simply a constant $ \ \frac14·\left( \ 1 \ + \ \left[\frac12 \right]^2 \ - \ 2 · \left[\frac12 \right]^3 \ \right)  \  $ $ = \ \frac14·\left( \ 1 \ + \  \frac14   \ - \ \frac14 \ \right) \ = \ \frac14 \ \ $ along that entire segment.  Hence, we have found that the function is zero at the vertices and equal to $ \ \frac14 \ $ at the midpoints of each edge of the triangular region (as well as for all the points with $ \ z_0 \ = \ \frac12 \ \ . $

It remains to evaluate the function $ \ \frac14·( \ 1 \ + \ z_0^2 \ - \ 2z_0^3 \ ) \ $ along this "mid-line" through the triangular region.  It would be rather easy to do so using calculus (and multi-variate calculus would make short work of this entire problem), but we can deal with this cubic function with a bit of effort.  If we "drop" the constant term for the time being, we can factor $ \ z_0^2 \ - \ 2z_0^3 \ = \ z_0^2·(1 \ - \ 2z_0) \ \ , \ $ which indicates that this function has a "double-zero" turning-point ("touching intercept") at $ \ z_0 \ = \ 0 \ $ and a third zero at $ \ z_0 \ = \ \frac12 \ \ . \ $  If we "vertically shift" the function "downward" to $ \ g(z_0) \ = \ z_0^2 \ - \ 2z_0^3 \ - \ \frac{1}{27} \ \ , \ $  we find that it can be factored as $ \ -\left(z_0 \ - \ \frac13 \right)^2  · \left(2z_0 \ + \ \frac13  \right) \ \ , \ $ which indicates that it has a turning-point (which opens downward) at $ \ z_0 \ = \ \frac13 \ $ and a third zero at $ \ z_0 \ = \ -\frac16 \ \ ; \ $ the other turning-point (which opens upward) at $ \ z_0 \ = \ 0 \ $ is this function's $ \ y-$intercept, $ \ g(0) \ = \ -\frac{1}{27} \ \ . \ $  If we now "shift" $ \ g(z_0) \ $ back "upward" by $ \ \frac{28}{27} \ $ units to $ \ 1 \ + \ z_0^2 \ - \ 2z_0^3 \ \ , \ $ we see that this function has a (local) minimum value of $ \ 1 \ $ at $ \ z_0 \ = \ 0 \ $ and a (local) maximum value of $ \ \frac{28}{27} \ $ at $ \ z_0 \ = \ \frac13 \ \ . \ $ [This is the most difficult part of the analysis to carry out without calculus.]  If we at last return to the "mid-line" function $ \ \frac14·( \ 1 \ + \ z_0^2 \ - \ 2z_0^3 \ ) \ \ , \ $ we see that it has the value we determined earlier at $ \ z_0 \ = \ 0 \ $ of $ \ \frac14·1 \ \ ; \ $ its maximum value of $ \ \frac14·\frac{28}{27} \ = \ \frac{7}{27} \ $ occurs at $ \ z_0 \ = \ \frac13 \ \ . $

[A graph of the mid-line function appears below; even with the vertically-exaggerated scale, it is clear that this function over $ \ 0 \ \le \ z_0 \ \le \ \frac12 \ $ is very "flat".]

The maximum value for $ \ xy + yz + xz -  2xyz \ $ in this planar region is thus $ \ \frac{7}{27} \ \ , \ $ occurring at $ \ \left(\frac{1 \ - \ z_0}{2} \ , \ \frac{1 \ - \ z_0}{2} \ , \ z_0 \right) \ = \ \left(\frac13 \ , \ \frac13 \ , \ \frac13  \right) \ \ , \ $ as the region and function symmetries suggested.

[image]

It perhaps should be said that the fact that the function is symmetrical (and reasonably simple) and the region in which it is applied is planar is largely what keeps the extremization within the reach of an algebraic approach.

Comment: I know basic calculus but not multivariate calculus

Comment: Where single-variable calculus shortens this answer (considerably) is in finding the maxima and minima along the "constant-$z_{0}$" segments and on the "mid-line" of the region where $ \ y \ = \ x \ \ . \ $  (You could then confirm with calculus what I've shown without it.)  If you come back sometime to this problem after you've learned partial differentiation (which isn't difficult), you'll be able to locate the maximum immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for proving that $f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx-2xyz\leq \frac{7}{27}$ if $x,y,z\in(0,1)$ and $x+y+z=1.$ We denote $x=X+1/3,y=Y+1/3, z=Z+1/3$ with $X,Y,Z\in [-1/3.2/3]$ and $X+Y+Z=0.$ We denote
$$A=-2(XY+YZ+ZX)=X^2+Y^2+Z^2$$ leading to
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{7}{27}-\frac{1}{6}(A+12XYZ).$$ If 2 of the three numbers $X, Y,Z$ are negative we have $A+12XYZ\geq 0.$ If not, without loss of generality we assume $Y$ and $Z$ non negative. As a consequence $0\leq Y+Z=-X\stackrel{(*)}
{\leq} 1/3$ and we get
$$A+12XYZ=(Y+Z)^2+Y^2+Z^2-12 (Y+Z)YZ\stackrel{(*)}
{\geq }2(Y^2+Z^2+YZ) -4YZ=2((Y-Z)^2+YZ)\geq 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$ we obtain a value $\frac{7}{27}.$

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$\frac{7}{27}-xy-xz-yz+2xyz=$$
$$=\frac{1}{27}\left(7(x+y+z)^3-27(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)+54xyz\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{27}\sum_{cyc}(7x^3-6x^2y-6x^2z+5xyz)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{54}\sum_{cyc}(14x^3-7x^2y-7x^2z-5x^2y-5x^2z+10xyz)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{54}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(7(x+y)-5z)\geq\frac{5}{54}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(x+y-z)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{5}{54}((x-z)^2(x+z-y)+(y-z)^2(y+z-x))\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{5}{54}((y-z)^2(x-y)+(y-z)^2(y-x))=0.$$